# Update a table based on the count values on another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, sql-update, aggregate

I'm using MS Access VBA to update a table in the database file based on the count values on another table, which references back to the table I want to update.

```
Table 1: request

 - Columns: requestID, requestStatus

Table 2: requestItem

 - Columns: requestItemID, requestID, requestItemStatus
```

1 request can have n request items, but 1 request item can be contained in only 1 request.

I want to update **request** table if all of request items of a request have "complete" **requestItemStatus**, updating the request's **requestStatus** to "complete" as well.

I tried the following at the first time:

```
Update request SET request.request_status_id = "complete" WHERE COUNT(SELECT requestItem.* FROM requestItem WHERE requestItem.requestID = request.requestID) = COUNT(SELECT requestItem.* FROM requestItem WHERE requestItem.requestID = request.requestID AND requestItem.request_item_status_id = "complete")
```

But VBA is complaining that SQL statement cannot have aggregate function in expression (COUNT()=).

What should I do here? Thanks for any help! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The query can be expressed as "Set the request as complete if none of the child request items has a state other than complete", i.e.:

```
UPDATE Request 
       SET request_status_id = "complete" 
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT 1 FROM RequestItem 
                        WHERE RequestItem.RequestId = Request.RequestID 
                        AND Request_item_status_id <> "complete")
```

Answer (score 0):

What Stuartd has above is likely the easiest way to do this. Below is an alternative if you are only wanting to update the actual records which are blank or <> completed. I hope this helps! Make sure to try it first in a test environment.

```
UPDATE Request SET RequestStatus = "Complete" WHERE RequestID IN (
SELECT Request.RequestID
FROM Request
JOIN (SELECT RequestItem.requestItemID, RequestItem.requestID, RequestItem.requestItemStatus
FROM RequestItem WHERE RequestItem.requestItemStatus <> "Complete") DONTUP ON DONTUP.requestID = Request.RequestID)
```